# Highcharts - Export server not generating image

Tags: server, export, highcharts

I have setup the export server for highcharts by following all the steps mentioned at http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server.

My test environment is windows server, tomcat 8.0.30, Phantom 2.0 and Java 1.8.0_71. No problem occurred during mvn install and mvn clean package and my application deployed successfully.

Export server URL is : http://localhost:9090/highcharts-export-web/ and highcharts export server page opens properly but when I click on the "Preview" button, I get "Internal server error". When I look at the tomcat logs, I see the following error:

[ERROR] [http-nio-9090-exec-4 01:35:42] (SVGConverter.java:requestServer:136) ja
va.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

When I look at the task manager, there are about 15 instances of PhantomJS.exe running. Also I could see only two files in C:\tomcat\webapps\highcharts-export-web\resources\js directory. These are codemirror-compressed.js and jquery-1.11.0.min.js. Seems like all the js files are compressed. Below is my app-convert.properties file:

```js
#### phantomjs properties ####

# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777

# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
#exec = /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = C:\\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe

# specify here an alternative location (the whole path!) for the script that starts an Phantomjs server. F.eks /home/bert/scripts/my-highcharts-convert.js
# Leave empty if you're using the script bundled with the export-server.
script =

#### connect properties used to connect with phantomjs running as HTTP-server ####
# all values in milliseconds

# specifies the timeout when reading from phantomjs when a connection is established
readTimeout = 60000

# timeout to be used when opening a communications link to the phantomjs server
connectTimeout = 10000

# the whole request to the phantomjs server is scheduled, max timeout can last to this value. This is because in java you can't rely on the above two timeouts.
maxTimeout = 65000

#### Pool properties ####

# number of phantomjs servers you can run in the pool.
poolSize = 10

# The pool is implemented as a BlockingQueue. When asking for a phantom server connection and nothing is available, it waits for the number of milliseconds defined by maxWait
maxWait = 6000

# Keep files in the temp folder for a certain retentionTime, defined in miliseconds
retentionTime = 60000
```

Answer (score 0):

After the Highcharts export server is moved to a separate GitHub repository, you have to copy the Highcharts javascript files to your export server project, *before* deploying.

Copy files like highcharts.js, highcharts-more.js, funnel.js (If you want to export funnel charts) to the folder `highcharts-export-convert/src/main/resources/phantomjs`

Read also: paragraph 2.3. [COPY HIGHCHARTS JS TO THE MAVEN CONVERT MODULE](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)